# Los mensajes no van a la base de datos

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un chat que tiene la siguiente estrutura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando envío el mensaje, no va a la base de datos. Ver:

**index.php**

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="chat-area">
      <header>
        <?php 
          $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['user_id']);
          $_SESSION['unique_id'] = $user_id;
          $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pd_users WHERE user_cod = '{$user_id}'");
          if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
          }else{
          //  echo "SELECT * FROM pd_users WHERE user_cod = '{$user_id}'";
            header("location: sistema/chat/");
          }
        ?>
        <a href="sistema/chat/" class="back-icon"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
        <img src="chat/php/images/usuario.jpeg" alt="">
        <div class="details">
          <span><?php echo $row['user_name']; ?></span>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="chat-box">
      </div>
      <form action="#" class="typing-area">
        <input type="text" class="incoming_id" name="incoming_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="message" class="input-field" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..." autocomplete="off">
        <button><i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i></button>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="chat/Javascript/chat.js"></script>
```

**chat.js**

```
const form = document.querySelector(".typing-area"),
incoming_id = form.querySelector(".incoming_id").value,
inputField = form.querySelector(".input-field"),
sendBtn = form.querySelector("button"),
chatBox = document.querySelector(".chat-box");

form.onsubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
}

inputField.focus();
inputField.onkeyup = ()=>{
    if(inputField.value != ""){
        sendBtn.classList.add("active");
    }else{
        sendBtn.classList.remove("active");
    }
}

sendBtn.onclick = ()=>{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "chat/php/insert-chat.php", true);
    xhr.onload = ()=>{
      if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){        
          if(xhr.status === 200){
              inputField.value = "";
              scrollToBottom();
          }
      }
    }
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
chatBox.onmouseenter = ()=>{
    chatBox.classList.add("active");
}

chatBox.onmouseleave = ()=>{
    chatBox.classList.remove("active");
}

setInterval(() =>{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "chat/php/get-chat.php", true);
    xhr.onload = ()=>{
      if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
          if(xhr.status === 200){
            let data = xhr.response;
            chatBox.innerHTML = data;
            if(!chatBox.classList.contains("active")){
                scrollToBottom();
              }
          }
      }
    }
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("incoming_id="+incoming_id);
}, 500);

function scrollToBottom(){
    chatBox.scrollTop = chatBox.scrollHeight;
  }
```

**insert-chat.php**

```
  session_start();
     if(isset($_SESSION['unique_id'])){
        include_once "config.php";
        $outgoing_id = $_SESSION['unique_id'];
        $incoming_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incoming_id']);
        $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);        
        if(!empty($message)){
            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO messages (incoming_msg_id, outgoing_msg_id, msg)
                                        VALUES ({$incoming_id}, '{$outgoing_id}', '{$message}')");
        }
    }else{
        header("location: sistema/chat/");
    }
```

La query funciona correctamente, pero parece que el problema está en ajax. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Lo siento, mi español.

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama el archivo en que está el primer bloque de código que nos muestras? Si no explicas bien el contexto será más complicado ayudarte. Además, ¿qué pinta un header location en un contexto de petición Ajax? ... eso no tiene ningún sentido, a lo sumo, devuelve un mensaje de error, pero no mandes el código a otro sitio en un contexto Ajax, donde el cliente espera una respuesta.

Comment: Hola A.Cedano. Incluye el nombre de archivo. No podía entender sobre el Ajax. El chat ya existía en la empresa para la que trabajo, porque fue creado por otro desarrollador que ya no trabaja aquí. No tengo conocimientos en Ajax o Jquery.

Comment: En caso de éxito, lo que hace tu código es esto: `if(xhr.status === 200){ inputField.value = ""; scrollToBottom();}` o sea, prácticamente nada. ¿Por qué dices que no funciona? ¿Qué entiendes tú por *ir a la base de datos*? Sea como sea, depura el código, emite mensajes desde el servidor, de éxito o de error y verifica en Javascript qué mensajes llegan. Si no ves mensajes, entonces pon `alert()` en tu código JS para verificar si entra o no en los diferentes bloques. Se trata de depurar el código. Viéndolo así, es complicado decirte qué es lo que está fallando.

Comment: El problema es que incluso dando código 200, los mensajes de formulario no llegan al archivo de inserción de chat.php para incluir en la base de datos. Sql es correcto, pero no tengo conocimientos en Ajax.

Comment: Como te dije, depura tu código y tus variables, por ejemplo, qué muestra un `alert(formData);` o un `console.log(formData);` en tu contexto de Ajax. Debes revisar qué estás mandando y cómo lo estás mandando.

Comment: Cuando doy la `alert(formData);` , devuelve `[object FormData]`

Comment: Hazlo con `console.log` y revisa la consola (supongo que sabes a lo que me refiero, si no, pregunta en otro comentario), allí podrás ver el objeto completo, con los datos.